Сложное предложение, состоящее из двух односоставных, или простое с однородными сказуемыми?
«Слушай своё сердце и не ошибёшься». Нужно ли поставить здесь запятую? Это сложное предложение, состоящее из двух односоставных определенно-личных или простое с однородными сказуемыми?

Правильно:
Слушай своё сЕрдце, и не ошибЁшься.
Пояснение
Это ССП, два односоставных определено-личных предложения.
Я не вижу причин считать их однородными сказуемыми, слишком много здесь неоднородности: разная грамматическая форма, причинно-следственные отношения между двумя частями ССП,  две фразы и два ударения с точки зрения интонации.
Впрочем, подобные задачи неоднозначны и требуют индивидуального подхода. Подобная тема обсуждалась на форуме:
Почему нет запятой перед союзом И между односоставными предложениями?
